# PHP form with checkboxes not inserting data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have encountered an issue, when trying to submit this form, with hidden checkboxes labeled by text. I use CSS to show/hide content instead of JavaScript and I need to do so.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="table_info3_form1">
<h3>Materialy</h3>
Materialy: <input type="text" name="materialy">
<label class="collapse" for="ajfarebne"><b>Aj farebne materialy ?: (click)</b></label>
<input id="ajfarebne" type="checkbox" name="ajfarebne">
<div>Menia sa farby pravidelne, alebo len obcas ?<input type="text" name="meniasa"/></div><br>
PC a PMMA: <input type="text" name="pcapmma">
<br>Iny transparentny material: <input type="text" name="inytransparentny"><br>
Frekvencia cistenia strojov: <input type="text" name="frekvencia"><br>
Najvacsi problem pri cisteni: <input type="text" name="najvacsiproblem"><br>
</form>
```

with this css (I add this, because it is necessary for work of showing/hiding):

```
.collapse{
display:block;
}
.collapse + input{
display:none;
}
.collapse + input + *{
display:none;
}
.collapse+ input:checked + *{
display:block;
}
```

and php code is like this(I store data in variables like this):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$materialy=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['materialy']);
$meniasa=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meniasa']);
... more variables

if(isset($_GET['qs']))
{
$id = $_GET['qs'];

if (isset($_POST['ajfarebne'])){ $ajfarebne=1; else $ajfarebne=0; //defining my checkbox variable value
```

then I insert values to database:

```
$query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties3 VALUES('', '$materialy', '$ajfarebne', '$meniasa'... more variables
```

and then I redirect:

```
if($query1)
{
$query1=mysql_query("select idfirma3 from properties3 where idfirma3='$id'");
$query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);


header("location:../firma/firma-properties.php?id=".$query4['idfirma3']."");
}
```

The problem:

**this form will do nothing. Meaning it won't store data into my table and eventually will not redirect to any location.**

What is wrong?

Comment: You really need to stop using the obsolete `mysql_query` before you hurt yourself. You're completely ignoring important [escaping concerns](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and are exposing yourself to a world of pain and suffering because this is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Switch to a modern interface like PDO and use data placeholders unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: At start page you use 
print_r($_POST);
this instruction print all data you post with form, so you can watch what you receive.

Enjoy your code

Comment: i got it working now and i am modernizing my code. I have a question: I do have a login page for this system, so it is neccessary to login to access this data. Is it a big issue to still not use PDO's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `mysqli_query` also make sure you are connected to your database and then do this:

```
if (mysqli_query($con, "INSERT... ")){
  ... //code here

}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, i have a code that i did not write that is located just after <?php tag defining that, so i am sure that the connection is alright. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @rudyherehello okay that is great. Now try using `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query` and see if it works. Also, use the `mysqli_error($con)` to see what error are you getting.

Comment: Ok, so i get an error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. Any ideas?

Comment: @rudyherehello you need to specify the column names in the INSERT statement... example `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");`

Comment: I now get Unknown column 'variablename' in 'field list

Comment: @rudyherehello do you have a column named 'variablename' ?

Comment: Nope, i posted that just for illustration. And i just want to say OOPS i got that error because i had my variablename like "onehundredtofivehundred" and in my database i had "100to500". I didnt realize it is a numbers word not a character word. I am really sorry for that last question.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. First of all, when you're using insert it's best to go ahead and give the query the column names. If your row count is off, then the query will fail.
2. From what you've shown you have nothing to out put the mysql query error if there is one. And the fact that it doesn't redirect sometimes, showcases that there is an error(mysql_query returned false, which is failure, so $query1 == false). You should call the mysql_error() function.
3. mysql_* is deprecated. You should switch to mysqli_*.
4. This looks to be a syntax error:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['ajfarebne'])){ $ajfarebne=1; else $ajfarebne=0;
   ```

You should change it to ternary, or fix the braces.

Comment: ah, to the point #4: the code actually continues there after the "{" .....it is not the exact code but an illustration. Thank you for your answer.